# joined table for has_and_belongs_to_many not migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I  created a joined table using

```
rails g employee_task employee:belongs_to task:belongs_to
```

When I try to migrate it (db:migrate) it keep showing me a PG:DATATYPEMISMATCH saying that employee_id and id are incompatible and that one is bigint and the other one is uuid. However, I already have uuid configured and all the other tables have it as id.

How do I fix this?

Here's the migration file

```rb
class CreateEmployeeTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :Employee_tasks, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.belongs_to :Employee, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :Task, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't `EmployeeTask belongs_to :User` be `EmployeeTask belongs_to :task`? And, why are you using capitalized symbols (`:Employee_tasks`, `:Employee`, and `:User`) instead of the downcase versions (`:employee_tasks`, `:employee`, and `:user`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```rb
class CreateEmployeesTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :employees_tasks, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :employee, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It still returns the same error. The foreign key is referring to a primary key and they're not the same type

Answer (score 0):

[`add_reference`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) (which is used by [`references`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references)/`belongs_to`) does not automatically infer the type from the target table. It just defaults to `type: :integer`.

To add a reference to an uuid column you need to manually specify the type:

```
class CreateEmployeesTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :employees_tasks, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :employee, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid
      t.belongs_to :task, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid
    end
  end
end
```

See [Rails issue #23422](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23422) and [the PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37583) that hopefully fixes the generators so that you don't have do this manually every time.

You should note though that `has_and_belongs_to_many` (HABTM) is headless - there is no model for the join table rows. So there is no point in adding an id or timestamps to the table as there is no way to actually query them. The only thing ever used will be the two foreign keys. The table naming scheme for HABTM is also at odds with the rest of rails - its *plural_plural* not *singular_plural*.

HABTM is actually pretty useless since you can't actually query the join table directly or add any attributes that describe the relation between the two models. I would instead set it up with [`has_many through:`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employee_tasks
  has_many :tasks, though: :employee_tasks
end

# rails g model EmployeeTask employee:belongs_to task:belongs_to
class EmployeeTask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :task
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employee_tasks
  has_many :employees, though: :employee_tasks
end
```

```
class CreateEmployeeTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :employee_tasks, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.belongs_to :employee, null: false, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid
      t.belongs_to :task, null: false, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```